# How to validate instanciate and validate children before save an object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I have a **department** model which have many users like this :

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :department
end
```

In my action **departement#edit** I have a **f.association** field in order to change users who belongs_to this department, but my issue is that I'm able to remove users without any error. Since department is not optional I'm expecting a validation error, but the users do not seem to be instanciated.

What would be the best way to validate that I am not removing users from my department, only adding them?